# when button pressed or when view Disappear in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, view, viewcontroller

I have 3 view controller.
First view controller has a button and second view controller has a button.

My third view controller has 2 buttons  (button 1 and button 2) when the button of first view controller or second view controller pressed it shows the third view controller, I want to write a code that:
 If first view controller button pressed or view disappear my third view controller button 1 hide else second view controller button pressed or view disappear my third view controller button 2 hide.

I tried many ways in swift but it doesn't work at all, can any help me with that please...

Comment: What you've tried? What's the problem? It's seems to unclear for understanding

Comment: if my "first view controller" disappear and my "third view controller" appear hide button 1 of my third view controller.

Comment: Can you add images clarifying what you want to achieve?

Comment: You need to pass any flag or data in third viewcontroller, that specify which button you press . And enable button according this flag .

Comment: thanks @Miteshjadav, can you write an example please.

Comment: Write your code how you push one view controller to  another

Answer (score 0):

Use like this : creates a new instance of ViewController.

```
class ViewController1 : UIViewController 
{
...

func goToSecondView() {
    var viewController = ViewController2()
    viewController. isFrom = 1
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
 }
}

class ViewController3 : UIViewController
{
var isFrom : Int?
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    if isFrom == 1
    {
    button.hidden = true Or button.enable = false
    }
    else isFrom == 2
   { 
    button2.hidden = true Or button2.enable = false
   }
}

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the value of isFrom shows nil  at the end, it doesn't pass the right value to another ViewController.

Comment: Give class name proper var viewController = ViewController3() , check your navigation object is set